# Can we have multi-dimensional values in pivot-table pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am using the pandas library for creating pivot tables in csv files.

The usual format of the pivot_table code is something like the bottom code.

```
 tips=read_csv('tips.csv')
`table=pd.pivot_table(tips, values='tip_pct', rows=['time', 'sex'], cols='smoker')`
```

I was wondering if we could add more than one dimension to the values field, like below?

```
List=read_csv('list.csv')
table=pd.pivot_table(List, values=['Applications','Acquisitions'], rows='Sub-Product',cols='Application Date', aggfunc='sum')
```

I tried the code above but the formatting was wrong so I was hoping that there is another way to get it?

ultimately i want to get this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cifML.png

All i can get now is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mbzK.png

This is a portion of my original list.csv file i'm trying to convert to a pivot table.

```
Application Date    Sub-Product Applications    Acquisitions
11/1/12                   GP              1    1
11/1/12                   GP              1    1
11/2/12                   GP              1    1
11/2/12                   GP              1    1
11/3/12                   GP              1    1
11/3/12                   GPF             1    1
11/4/12                   GPF             1    1
11/4/12                   GPF             2    2
11/5/12                   GPF             1    1
11/5/12                   GPF             1    1
11/6/12                   GPF             1    1





   This is what im trying to achieve for my pivot table. 

     1. Cols : Application Date
     2. Row labels: Sub-Product
     3. Values: Application, Acquisitions

            Row Labels        11/1/2012 11/2/2012   11/3/2012
            **GP**          
            Applications    190     207            65
            Acquisitions    164     168            54
            **GPF**         
            Applications    1391      1430           1269
            Acquisitions    1124      1142           992
            **Innovative Gateway**          
            Applications    2      1    
            Acquisitions    2      1
```

But what I am getting is

```
  Sub-Product   ('Applications', '1/1/13')('Applications', '1/10/13')
    GP                                48    134 
    GPF                              600    1099    
    Innovative Gateway               1    2
```

this is my code:

```
> list=pd.read_csv("List.csv") 
> df=DataFrame(list)
> table=pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Applications','Acquisitions'], rows='Sub-Product',cols='Application Date',aggfunc=np.sum)
>table.to_csv('file.csv')
```

So the issue now is that i am unable to have more than one value for the values field and the date seems to be jumbled up. Please help!

Thanks

---

The date issue can be solved with

```
xl2["Application Date"] = pd.to_datetime(xl2["Application Date"], format="%m/%d/%y")
```

right now my only problem is the fact that the values field cant take more than one value and wondering if anyone has any idea on how to use stack or reshape functions.

Comment: What do you mean formatting was wrong?

Comment: Hi Andy, could you take a look at the links i shared?

Comment: It looks like you can stack/reshape into the correct form. Please copy and paste the actual text rather than an image... this doesn't seem to match the original arguments :S

Comment: Edited my question. Hopes it makes more sense now.

Comment: I think you're looking to do some kind of stack / unstack afterwards (most likely `.stack(0)`)

Comment: Yeah that was the problem! I got the pivot table right, but the rows were not in the format i wanted them to be. Stack was the solution. Thanks Andy :) !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it add them as the top column level:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, (5, 5)), columns=list('abcde'))

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  2  1  1  2  0
1  0  1  2  0  2
2  1  1  1  0  2
3  0  0  1  1  0
4  2  0  2  0  1

In [3]: df.pivot_table(values=['a', 'b'], rows='c', cols='d')
Out[3]:
   a            b
d  0   1   2    0   1   2
c
1  1   0   2  1.0   0   1
2  1 NaN NaN  0.5 NaN NaN
```